# 95th percentile of a histogram

Tags: statistics, percentile

I need advice on what is the appropriate approach for communicating thorough a graph the low and high work loads of my web server. To be able to distribute the computers resources at the appropriate times of heavy and low workloads. I have the number of HTTPS requests over a time period. Additionally I have the data over the same period that shows the number of unique users that are signed in longer then half hour. These users are the users that matter and use the most resources and I want to distribute my memory and CPU accordingly.   The half hour doesn't have to be continuous but at least a total of 1/2 hour or more within the hour to be considered an user.  I was thinking of doing a graph that shows the rate, HTTPS request per the number of users over a interval (i.e per hour).  Does this make sense?  Does it also make sense to do 95th percentile of HTTPS requests. Not sure how you do that though.  If I look at a period of one week at a interval of one hour, for example 25th to 31st, would my data be more accurate if go back as far as a year and compute the 95 percentile of HTTPS requests? Then I would divide that 95 percentile for that interval of hour by current users of the actual hour that I was looking at?

Example:
I have 100 request between 2PM and 3PM and during that hour I have 5 users. 100 /5 = 20 HTTPS per user during 2 PM and 3 PM ...that would point 1 and then I would do the same for point 2 but hour later from 3 PM to 4 PM 100 HTTPS request with 20 users 100 /20 = 5 HTTPS request per user and I continue to do this until what every period I defined, lets say a week.

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding of your question, you want to look at HTTPS requests per user per hour, and then you want to look at this quantity over time? E.g. a relevant data point might be "at 2pm the average user made 50 HTTPS requests". After collecting this data, you want to look at the 95th percentile of such data points, e.g. "95% of hours, the average user makes less than 100 HTTPS requests" (here we average over users each hour). Or did you want to look at something like "95% of users make less than 100 HTTPS requests on average" (here we fix each user and average over hours).

Comment: @nullUser "HTTPS requests per user per hour, and then you want to look at this quantity over time?"  So I have 100 request between 2PM and 3PM and during that hour I have 5 users.  100 /5 = 20 HTTPS per user  during 2 PM and 3 PM ...that would point 1 and then I would do the same for point 2 but hour later from 3 PM to 4 PM 100 HTTPS request with 20 users 100 /20 = 5 HTTPS request per user  Does this make sense now?

Comment: Yes now I understand, for hour $t$ you have $R(t)$ requests and $U(t)$ users. You are interested in graphing $R(t)/U(t)$. Now what do you mean about the 95th percentile of HTTPS requests? Do you just want to know "95% of hours for which I have data collected, there were less than X requests"?

Comment: @nullUser How do you general use percentile?  I was thinking of using 95 percentile of HTTPS request over x historical weeks per interval.  For example, if I had 100 HTTPS request for 1 PM Monday 26th Jan, 150 HTTPS request 1 PM Monday 19th Jan, 50 HTTPS request 1 PM Monday 12th Jan.   The I would take the 95 percentile of that.  Does make any sense?

Comment: So you collect $R(t)$ over a bunch of times, then you put them all together and make a histogram/dot plot/... and you want the 95th percentile of that? That just means you want a number $x$ such that $95\%$ of the values you collected are less than $x$.

Comment: Little confused on what x would be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20881/discussion-between-nulluser-and-user3590149).

Comment: What question are you trying to answer, specifically? Do you want to predict high load periods on the server, or the times of the most active users (these may differ).

Comment: The most active and least active times for users.  High congestion.